# Get the session in client components with Authjsv5 and next14

Tags: reactjs, next-auth, next.js14

I am trying to configure my next14 app(with app router) with authjs@beta with a custom backend.
After configuring it i am correctly able to call the auth() method inside server component and i correctly getm my session data, but when i try to use the useSession hook inside client components i get "{data: null, status: 'unauthenticated', update: ƒ}"

Since the begining i had a lot of dificulties because the data of the session.user is not like the pre-defined data (email, name, etc) so i am getting the data from the token and passing it to the user via the session callback

here is my code:

**"/auth/auth.config.ts"**

```
import type { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth";

const isTokenExpired = (token: string): Boolean => {
  const base64Url = token.split(".")[1];
  const base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, "+").replace(/_/g, "/");
  const decodedPayload = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(base64, "base64").toString("binary"));
  const tokenExpirationDate = new Date(decodedPayload.exp * 1000).getTime();
  const now = Date.now();
  return now >= tokenExpirationDate;
};

export const authConfig = {
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ auth, request: { nextUrl } }) {
      const isLoggedIn = !!auth?.user;

      if (nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/login") && isLoggedIn) {
        //NO ESTA ENTRANDO
        // Redirecciona al usuario a la pag root si estan logeados e intentan acceder a la pag de  login.
        return Response.redirect(new URL("/", nextUrl));
      } else if (isLoggedIn) {
        // Revisa si el usuario esta en alguna ruta del root o mayor("/", "/users", "/dashboard", etc.)
        const isOnRootOrAbove = nextUrl.pathname === "/" || nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/");
        if (isOnRootOrAbove) {
          return true; // Si el Usuario esta en root o una ruta mayor a root y esta logeado, permite el acceso.
        }
      }

      return false; // Por defecto niega el acceso.
    },
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
      if (user) {
        return { ...token, ...user };
      }

      if (!!token.accessToken && isTokenExpired(token.accessToken)) {
        console.log("token expired!");
        return null;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      if (token.user && token.accessToken) {
        //@ts-ignore
        session.user = token.user;
        session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
  providers: [],
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;
```

**"/auth/auth.ts"**

```
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import NextAuth, { AuthError } from "next-auth";
import { authConfig } from "./auth.config";

const credentialsConfig = Credentials({
  async authorize(credentials) {
    const { username, password } = credentials;

    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    const body = JSON.stringify({ username, password });
    try {
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost/api/auth/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers,
        body,
      });
      const user = await res.json();
      if (user?.status === 0) {
        return null;
      }

      return user;
    } catch (err) {
      throw new AuthError();
    }
  },
});

export const { auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
  ...authConfig,
  session: { strategy: "jwt" },
  jwt: { maxAge: 60 * 15 },
  providers: [credentialsConfig],
});
```

**"/src/app/providers.tsx"**

```
"use client";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import { ReactNode } from "react";
const Providers = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  return <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>;
};

export default Providers;
```

**"/src/app/layout.tsx"**

```
import "@ui/globals.css";
import "@radix-ui/themes/styles.css";
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Theme, ThemePanel } from "@radix-ui/themes";
import { LayoutContextProvider, Layout, Navbar } from "@components";
import { DefaultSidebar } from "@layout";
import StoreProvider from "@redux/StoreProvider";
import Providers from "./providers";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "title",
  description: "description",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <Providers>
      <html lang="es" suppressHydrationWarning>
        <body>
          <Theme appearance="dark" accentColor="red" panelBackground="translucent">
            <StoreProvider>
              <LayoutContextProvider>{children}</LayoutContextProvider>
            </StoreProvider>
            {/* <ThemePanel /> */}
          </Theme>
        </body>
      </html>
    </Providers>
  );
}
```

**"/src/page/(home)/prueba/page.tsx"**

```
"use client";
import { Header } from "@components";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";

export default function Prueba() {
  const session = useSession();
  console.log(session);
  return <Header>Prueba</Header>;
}
```

my actions:
**"/src/app/lib/actions.ts"**

```
"use server";
import { z } from "zod";
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { auth, signIn, signOut } from "@auth/auth";
import { AuthError } from "next-auth";

const SignInFormSchema = z.object({
  username: z.string().min(4, {
    message: "Username must be at least 4 characters long.",
  }),
  password: z.string().min(1, {
    message: "Password must not be empty",
  }),
});

export type State = {
  errors?: {
    username?: string[];
    password?: string[];
    auth?: string[];
  };
  message?: string | null;
};

export async function authenticate(
  prevState: State,
  formData: FormData
): Promise<State | undefined> {
  const validatedFields = SignInFormSchema.safeParse({
    username: formData.get("username"),
    password: formData.get("password"),
  });
  if (!validatedFields.success) {
    return {
      errors: validatedFields.error.flatten().fieldErrors,
      message: "Campos incompletos. no puede inicial sesion",
    };
  }
  try {
    await signIn("credentials", formData);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof AuthError) {
      switch (error.type) {
        case "CredentialsSignin":
          return { message: "Invalid credentials." };
        default:
          return {
            message: "Something went wrong.",
          };
      }
    }
    revalidatePath("/");
    redirect("/");
  }
}

export async function logout(): Promise<void> {
  await signOut();
}
```

I tried setting up the SessionProvider but I still get an object without the session.